# Charles Proxy for iPhone simulation re-direct subdomain

Tags: xcode, charles-proxy

I am trying to use the iPhone xcode simulator and need to map my dev. addresses to point to  on windows and osx I can just make an adjustment in the hosts file but in the iPhone simulator I cannot which is why I am thinking to use Charles.  How can I configure it to do this?